# xvfb never stops executing

Tags: php, xvfb

I have a simple command line here.. If I run it from a terminal it completes in about 1-2 sec, but if running it from php it never stops executing!? Why is that?

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /var/www/input.html /var/www/output.pdf
```

## from php

```
exec('xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /var/www/input.html /var/www/output.pdf');
```

## with sudo

```
sudo -u www-data xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /var/www/input.html /var/www/output.pdf
```

This doesn't create the output file but returns an error

```
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

## pipe stdout/stderr

Here both `xcfb.err` and `xvfb.out` are created but both files are empty. The command never completes executing

```
exec('xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf '.$path.'/email.html '.$path.'/output.pdf > '.$path.'/xvfb.out 2> '.$path.'/xvfb.err');
```

Comment: Maybe your PHP has an endless loop and the command is actually being executed multiple times. It's impossible to tell without looking at the rest of your code.

Comment: no its not.. the script only has this one line

Comment: Try `exec('whoami');` to figure out which user PHP is being executed as. If that is different than the user you are executing it by the command line with try doing, for example `sudo -u www-data xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf /var/www/input.html /var/www/output.pdf` (substitute `www-data` for the actual user) and see what happens.

Comment: (the second command you execute by command line, the first in PHP, in case that wasn't clear)

Comment: Also, if you don't have `sudo` use `su - <username> -c "<command>"`

Comment: Try also once redirecting error output: `exec('xvfb-run ... > /tmp/xvfb.out 2> /tmp/xvfb.err');`. It looks like xvfb-run is asking for input or something like that. You might even try piping `yes` before xvfb-run, just in case(`'yes | xvfb-run ...'`).

Comment: Have just tried your last command.. both `xvfb.err` and `xvfb.out` is created but empty.. No `output.pdf` and the command never completes executing